# reload jquery $(function() from within function

Tags: jquery, function

I have a js app that loads on page load.

```
    var lang = 'en';
    i18n.setLng(lang, function(err, t) { /* loading done */console.log('loaded ' + lang) });

    $(function() {
      Mirador({
        "id": "viewer",
        "layout": "1x1"
      });
    });
```

However I wanted to be able to dynamically switch the language, so added a small language switcher.

Html

```
  <div id="switch">English</div>
  <div id="viewer"></div>
```

JS

```
    $('#switch').click(function(){
     if(lang==='de') {
        lang = 'en';
     $("#switch").html("Other");
   } else {
     lang = 'de';
     $("#switch").html("English");

   }
  });
```

But although it changes the variable lang, it doesnt reload the mirador app. I understand I want to reload the page but with the new variable Im just struggling for the right syntax

Comment: If you reload the page the changes you made will be lost, because you're reloading the page.

Comment: Your Miradir call is inside a self invoking function that only runs once you need to call it after every language change.

Comment: @daveNewton yeah thats why I didnt want to just use a reload, but just reload the mirador content.
I think I see the error of my ways too now.

Answer (score 0):

$(function() {}); this is a document ready function. This is triggered automatically when page document is ready on the browser. You do not need to call it inside any other function. Even you can call Mirador function mutlitple time as you need. In my example Mirador is called when document is ready state as well as when user clicks and changes language. Mirador function settings you can do as per your need

```
$(function() {
      Mirador({
        "id": "viewer",
        "layout": "1x1"
      });

 $('#switch').click(function(){
     if(lang==='de') {
        lang = 'en';
    //reload app page
   } else {
     lang = 'de';
     $("#switch").html("English");
// reload app page
   }
  });

});
```

Comment: Why the same code twice put the Mirador initilization inside of a function and call the function ?

Comment: i have given you an idea how the flow will work with document ready function. If you do not need to reinitialize mirador function multiple time and there is a process to reload page you can replace mirador initialization code from click function. I have updated my code

Comment: What does "reload app page" mean? If you reload the page everything goes away.

Comment: @dave I think he means on click re initilize the Mirador app.